# How to covert a BufferedSource in scala to InputStream?

Tags: java, scala

I was reading a file from classpath in scala using scala.io.Source using fromResources which provides with a BufferedSource. How can I convert it to an InputStream as a java method invoked expects inputstream.

```
scala.io.Source.fromResource("keystore.jks")
```

Comment: The best option is probably to implement the API yourself. Or consider using something more robust like **fs2**. Or, if you don't care about the lazy nature of `Source` then yeah, just read everything in memory.

Comment: `Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("keystore.jks")`

Comment: Just read it directly as `InputStream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a BufferedSource to `byte[]` and put it ByteArrayInputStream: something like this will work:

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.InputStream

val bufferedSource: Source = Source.fromResource("keystore.jks")
val inputStream: InputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(bufferedSource.getLines().mkString("\n").getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```